# FUELPHP ORM: Database view 'viewname' is defined without columns

Tags: orm, fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

I am using ORM in FuelPHP to fetch some data on a table view I created in my data base.

I followed the instruction that is given [here](http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/12006/orm-how-to-use-view-tables#Item_3) but I'm getting an error as seen on the title above. Here is a screenshot of the error for reference (http://prntscr.com/72ssqc).

Here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/ips5VCzV

Here is a screenshot of the view Table:
http://prntscr.com/72st1e

Answer (score 0):

Your view definition is wrong, it misses the 'columns' array, as the message explains.

```
protected static $_views = array(
    'hugot_summary' => array(
        'columns' => array(
            'id',
            'user_id',
            'photo_id',
            'hugot',
            'url',
            'comment_count',
            'upvotes',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at'
        ),
    ),
);
```